# Python syntax error for a simple if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

I get a syntax error in my if statement:

```
print "Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!"

original = raw_input("Please enter a word to be translated: ")
word_length = len(original)

def length_check():
    If (word_length) > 0 : <-- This colon brings up the following error:
        return original


File "python", line 7
    If (word_length) > 0 :
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 5):

`If` should be changed to `if`. Observe the lowercase `i`.

```
>>> If True:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> if True:
        print True


True
```

You may want to read up [The Python Doc's entry on Control Flow](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements).